# Dificultad con seguridad de mi Github Page luego de conectarle un dominio de Godaddy

Tags: github, ssl, certificado-ssl, github-pages, godaddy

Posterior a ponerle mi dominio a mi Github Page esta aparece como insegura.

El video que seguí para hacer la integración de mi dominio personal con el de Github Page fue este https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8kfAZOjgR0

Lo que me gustaría es saber **¿Como puedo ponerle en certificado SSL (creo que es ese) para que mi página aparezca como segura?**

**¿Que es lo que tengo que hacer para que mi página sea segura?**

Comment: Lo más recomendable es que hables con Gogaddy y que ellos te configuren el SSL. Yo no creo que cobren ya que la mayoría de Hostings ya dan el SSL. Si por alguna razón no quieres o no puedes pagar, puedes buscar un SSL Gratis con [https://letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/es/). Aunque pueda que solo sea necesario que lo actives en el Hosting.